# For holomorphic function $f_j$, with $|f_j|\leq 2^{-j}$, is $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} f_j(z)$ converges to a holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove following

If $f_j : U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ are holomorphic and $|f_j| \leq 2^{-j}$, then prove that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} f_j(z)$ converges to a holomorphic function on $U$.

First i see that summation is bounded

\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} f_j(z) \leq \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}|f_j(z)| \leq \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}2^{-j} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=2
\end{align}

What i am in trouble with is showing that this function is converges and is really holomorphic.

Comment: I think the limit of a series of uniformly converging holomorphic functions is holomorphic.

Comment: Show for any $K\subset U$ compact, the series converges uniformly to some continuous function. By Morea's Theorem, you have holomorphicity.

Comment: Morera's theorem isn't really complicated :  If a sequence of holomorphic functions $g_n(z)$ converges uniformly on $U$ to $g(z)$, then $\int_\gamma g(z) dz = \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_\gamma g_n(z) dz = 0$ for every closed contour $\gamma \subset U$. And this is enough for showing that $G(z) = \int_a^z g(w)dw$ is well-defined (it doesn't depend on the chosen path $a \to z$) and is holomorphic on $U$, and hence analytic by the Cauchy integral formula. Of course $g(z) = G'(z)$ is analytic too

Comment: writing $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} f_j(z) \le \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}|f_j(z)|$ makes no sense.

Comment: @user1952009 That's incorrect unless $U$ is simply connected.

Comment: @zhw you are right, $U$ doesn't need to be simply connected, but we need to write it as $\cup_k D_k$ where $D_k$ are simply connected, and consider each one separately.